# What does `long unsigned typedef int long ullong;` mean?

Tags: c++, typedef

In [cppreference page of typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef),  there's an example:

```
// typedef can be used anywhere in the decl-specifier-seq
long unsigned typedef int long ullong;
```

I can't figure out what this mean.... pls help?

Comment: There's a hyperlink to [declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations), so you can find out, what *decl-specifier-seq* is.

Comment: @TavianBarnes so the rule is just i) typedef can appear anywhere in one declaration, and ii) duplicated things (e.g. `long`) can be ignored?

Comment: `long` is not ignored the second time. `long long` is a different type from `long`. If you include `long` a third time, there will be an error.

Comment: @Brian so `long unsigned typedef int long ullong;` equals to `typedef unsigned long long int ullong;`?

Comment: @TavianBarnes there are two `long` in there

Comment: @athos yes, they mean the same thing, like I said in my answer

Comment: Did you read the comment above the statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the same thing as

```
typedef unsigned long long int ullong;
```

The five words `typedef`, `unsigned`, `long`, `long`, and `int` are *decl-specifier*s forming a single *decl-specifier-seq,* and (with some possible edge case exceptions) the meaning or validity of a *decl-specifier-seq* does not depend on the order of the *decl-specifiers.*

Note that `int static x;` means the same thing as `static int x;`, and `void virtual f();` means the same thing as `virtual void f();`, to give some additional examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long long int
```

is a data type in C++. This line basically creates an alias for it: "ullong".